# Titanium Alloy: Can't Get Row Data To Print To A New Row It Is Always Overwriting The Previously Written Data

Tags: view, titanium, rows, titanium-alloy

I was hoping one of you could help me figure out why my row data keeps writing to the same row and overwriting the previously written data instead of starting on a new row after every iteration. Here's what I have so far:

*This alloy.js file below gets the information I need for the app from the server and passes it to the `formateData()` function in the index.js file.*

**alloy.js**

```
GetDataRequest("http:somejsondata/data.json");


 function GetDataRequest(url)
 {
    var xhr = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({             
    onload: function(e) 
    {
        Alloy.Globals.formateAnimalData(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText));
    },

    onerror: function(e) {
        Ti.API.debug("STATUS: " + this.status);
        Ti.API.debug("TEXT:   " + this.responseText);
        Ti.API.debug("ERROR:  " + e.error);
        alert('There was an error retrieving the remote data. Try again.');
    },
    timeout:5000

    });
    xhr.open("GET", url);
    xhr.send();
}
```

**index.js**

```
var appData = [];

Alloy.Globals.formateAnimalData = function(data)
{   
    console.log("I was also called");
    for (var i = 1; i <=8; i++)
    {
        var row = {
            name: data.animals[i].name,
            animal: data.animals[i].animal,
            food: data.animals[i].food
        };
        appData.push(Alloy.createController('index', row).getView());
        //console.log(appData); 
    }
};

var args = arguments[0] || {};

$.name.text = args.name || '';
$.animal.text = args.animal || '';  
$.food.text = args.food || '';


$.table.setData(appData);
$.index.open();
```

**index.xml**

```
<Alloy>
    <TabGroup id='index'>
        <Tab title="Tab 1" icon="KS_nav_ui.png">
            <Window id='main' class='' title="Zoo">
                <TableView>
                    <TableViewRow id='table'>
                        <Label id ='name'   class ='label'></Label>
                        <Label id ='animal' class ='label'></Label>
                        <Label id ='food'   class ='label'></Label>             
                    </TableViewRow>
                </TableView>
            </Window>
        </Tab>
    </TabGroup>
</Alloy>
```

I should note that the:

```
$.table.setData(appData);
```

line in the index.js file doesn't work. The data still prints to the screen even if this line is not in there. The reason for this I think is because the following line:

```
appData.push(Alloy.createController('index', row).getView());
```

is not pushing a row of objects into the **appData array** and infact when I log the contents of the appData array to the screen I get:

```
           (
[INFO] :       "[object index]",
[INFO] :       "[object index]",
[INFO] :       "[object index]",
[INFO] :       "[object index]",
[INFO] :       "[object index]",
[INFO] :       "[object index]",
[INFO] :       "[object index]",
[INFO] :       "[object index]"
[INFO] :   
           )
```

I am just trying to get it so that it prints the animals: Name, Type and Food Preference to row 1 and the next animals Name, Type and Food Preference to row 2 and so on.

Answer (score 1):

It's an ugly way to do. In this case, your main problem is this line :

```
appData.push(Alloy.createController('index', row).getView());
```

using `getView()` on your index controller will give you the top-level view, in this case the `TabGroup` of id **index**. 
If you really want to keep it that way, you have to supply *'table'* as arguments to ask for the `TableViewRow`

```
appData.push(Alloy.createController('index', row).getView('table'));
```

However, you are assigning to the newly created index controller and not to the original one instantiated by Alloy at starting....

You can try to create another controller named for instance *row*, and create an associated xml view this way :

**row.xml**

```
<Alloy>
    <TableViewRow id="row">
        <Label id="name" class="label"></Label>
        <Label id="animal" class="label"></Label>
        <Label id="food" class="label"></Label>
    </TableViewRow>
</Alloy>
```

**row.js**

```
var args = arguments[0] || {};

$.row.text = args.name || '';
$.row.text = args.animal || '';  
$.row.text = args.food || '';
```

And, refactor the rest the following way. I'm using events to communicate easily with the original instantiated index controller.

**index.xml**

```
<Alloy>
    <TabGroup id='index'>
        <Tab title="Tab 1" icon="KS_nav_ui.png">
            <Window id='main' class='' title="Zoo">
                <TableView id="table"/>
            </Window>
        </Tab>
    </TabGroup>
</Alloy>
```

**index.js**

```
/* Store rows somewhere */
$._rows = [];

/* Append row each time it's needed */
$.addEventListener('newrow', function (newrowEvent) {
    $._rows.push(newrowEvent.row);
});

/* Refresh only on demand */
$.addEventListener('refreshrows', function () {
    $.table.setData($._rows);
});

$.index.open();
```

**alloy.js**

```
/* ...
   Your previous function with the call to formateAnimal updated
*/


function formateAnimalData(data) {   
    for (var i = 1; i <=8; i++) {
        var rowContent = {
            name: data.animals[i].name,
            animal: data.animals[i].animal,
            food: data.animals[i].food
        };
        Ti.app.fireEvent('newrow', {
            row: Alloy.createController('row', rowContent).getView()
        });
    }
    Ti.app.fireEvent('refreshrows');
};
```

This should be a workaround a bit nicer. Keep in mind that, when you create a controller, the code that you put in the file's scope is executed only once; Also, each time you're calling `createController`, you'll get a new instance of that kind of controller; Do not try to modify other instances from the new instance.. This is weird and inefficient.

Finally, avoid putting *bloc scopes* above functions or control structures.

```
for ( ...; ...; ...)
{

}
```

or

```
function ()
{

}
```

are bad ideas. You're in JavaScript and semicolons aren't necessary for each statement or at least, the compiler will not complain and you're likely to obtain strange silent errors ...